# Microsoft Office programs do not open following update

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office

I've just turned on my laptop. I was using Word and Excel not one hour ago.

Now when I open any file (or either application directly) nothing happens. My computer doesn't crash or lag, but neither Word nor Excel will start.

Using Windows 10, and Word and Excel just updated themselves to something. Latest release. They are both Office 2016 products.

I've restarted my laptop a few times.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at Task Manager to see if the process (for Word or Excel) is running but is just not visible?

Answer (score 0):

I have been having issues with this as well. I have the Microsoft Office 365 Business ClickToRun 2016 version.
I had to roll back the update to a known stable release.

To rollback, open CMD as administrator and enter these lines:

```
 cd %programfiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun
 officec2rclient.exe /update user updatetoversion=16.0.6366.2056
```

This took me back to a January release.

Here is a list of updates: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt592918.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Here is the rollback article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2770432